# How can I get Ubuntu 20.04.5 to connect to a hybrid WPA2/WPA3 network on an early 2015 MacBook Pro?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-20.04, wpa

I've looked at various questions here but in my situation, my WiFi **is** working on my early 2015 MacBook Pro on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

The issue I'm running into is Ubuntu won't connect to hybrid WPA2/WPA3 networks.

This theory is based on the fact that if I create a hotspot with WPA2/WPA3 and then drop down to WPA2-only, Ubuntu connects (yeay!).

I don't think it's hardware issue as the MBP connects to WPA2/WPA3 networks when in macOS Monterey (verified it chooses WPA3) and another lightweight Linux distro I'm playing around with.

Does anyone know how to fix (or troubleshoot) this issue so Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS is able to connect to a hybrid WPA2/WPA3 network?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290589/how-to-use-wpa3-with-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: ah - this might help. I just booted into macOS and confirmed it’s connecting to my local WiFi network over WPA3 so it seems Ubuntu can’t make up its mind when presented with a hybrid WPA2/WPA3 network.